# iOS / Xcode - Navigation Item BackBarButtonItem title shows the one of the previous controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationitem

i have 2 View Controllers connected by a segue within a Navigation Controller and I edited the back items titles in **Interface Builder**.

My problem is, that the **BackBarButtonItem** of the second controller shows the title of the first (and presenting) controller's **BackBarButtonItem**, no matter what I set for Back on the second controller's NavigationItem.

The only thing I've done is setting the leftBarButtonItem for the first Controller:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Close", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backTapped:")
```

Now all NavigationItems of presented Controllers show "Close". Does anyone have an idea, what's going on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Setting the button's title by creating a UIBarButtonItem and setting is as leftBarButtonItem in the **second** controller too works, but this is more a workaround than a solution.

Comment: For some reason, removing the code line mentioned in the question does not change the bahaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure desired back button item title on the view controller to which back will be performed, e.g. on previous one.

Comment: That's it. My misunderstanding was setting the _BACK title_ on the _NavigationItem_ in InterfaceBuilder does not set the title for the back button of current controller, but for the back buttons in **presented** controllers.